# Problema en consulta MySql que no logro identificar

Tags: php, mysql

me encuentro creando un buscador, para ello ya tengo la consulta funcionando, al final de la consulta envió el parámetro "LIMIT", pues con esa consulta regreso los resultados y construyo la paginación, sin embargo tengo un probelama (precisamente con la paginación que no logro identificar).

Esta es mi consulta original que funciona sin probelam:

```
select  v.id as idvcante, v.ky, v.titulo, 
municipios.nombre as municipio, estados.nombre as estado, e.id as idempresa, 
e.empresa, e.img_perfil, 
empresas_contratos_vacantes.tipo, empresas_rangosal_vacantes.rango, 
v.fechapublicacion, 
empresas_nivexp_vacantes.nivel as experiencia, vacantes_cat.categoria, 
vacantes_subcat.subcategoria from vacantes as v 
inner join municipios on municipios.id=v.id_municipio 
inner join estados on estados.id=v.id_estado 
inner join empresas as e on e.id=v.id_empresa 
inner join empresas_contratos_vacantes on 
empresas_contratos_vacantes.id=v.id_contrato 
inner join empresas_rangosal_vacantes on 
empresas_rangosal_vacantes.id=v.id_rangosalario 
inner join empresas_nivexp_vacantes on 
empresas_nivexp_vacantes.id=v.id_experiencia 
inner join vacantes_cat on vacantes_cat.id=v.id_categoria 
inner join vacantes_subcat on vacantes_subcat.id=v.id_subcat where 
v.id_estado=30 and v.titulo like "%asesor de crédito%" or titulo like 
'%asesor%' or titulo like '%crédito%' order by visitas DESC LIMIT 5,5
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema radica en que, necesito hacer esta misma consulta, pero sin el límite (**LIMIT 5,5**), para saber el número total de registros que esa busqueda en específico me está generando. Para ello, se me ocurrió agregar esta línea:

```
(select count(*) from vacantes where v.id_estado=30 and v.titulo like 
"%asesor de crédito%" or titulo like '%asesor%' or titulo like '%crédito%' ) 
as total
```

Quedando entones la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
select (select count(*) from vacantes where v.id_estado=30 and v.titulo like 
"%asesor de crédito%" or titulo like '%asesor%' or titulo like '%crédito%' ) 
as total, v.id as idvcante, v.ky, v.titulo, municipios.nombre as municipio, 
estados.nombre as estado, e.id as idempresa, e.empresa, e.img_perfil, 
empresas_contratos_vacantes.tipo, empresas_rangosal_vacantes.rango, 
v.fechapublicacion, empresas_nivexp_vacantes.nivel as experiencia, 
vacantes_cat.categoria, vacantes_subcat.subcategoria from vacantes as v 
inner join municipios on municipios.id=v.id_municipio inner join estados on 
estados.id=v.id_estado inner join empresas as e on e.id=v.id_empresa inner 
join empresas_contratos_vacantes on 
empresas_contratos_vacantes.id=v.id_contrato inner join 
empresas_rangosal_vacantes on 
empresas_rangosal_vacantes.id=v.id_rangosalario inner join 
empresas_nivexp_vacantes on empresas_nivexp_vacantes.id=v.id_experiencia 
inner join vacantes_cat on vacantes_cat.id=v.id_categoria inner join 
vacantes_subcat on vacantes_subcat.id=v.id_subcat where v.id_estado=30 and 
v.titulo like "%asesor de crédito%" or titulo like '%asesor%' or titulo like 
'%crédito%' order by visitas DESC LIMIT 5,5,
```

Todo para tener esta columna. EL problema es que por alguna razón no me genera el mismo numero de resultados entonces como ese valor lo ocupo para hacer la paginación, en donde debe mostrar 17 resultados, en algunos casos muestra 48 :( (me refiero ya visualmente en el sistema que estoy desarrollando)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces concretamente: ¿Alguien me puede ayudar a idenfiticar que estoy haciendo mal o en dado caso como puedo hacer esto de mejor manera?

Muchas  gracias por su tiempo pero sobre todo por la ayuda.

PD: Hay que tomar en cuenta que necesito saber siempre en cada consulta el total de resultados que la búsqueda genera (pues lo necesito en el código para construir los resultados y la paginación), aunque solo se me estén listando  5, 10 o X Número pues los resultados, eso van a depender del parámetro LIMIT que mando al final.

Comment: pero si le estas pasando el limit, no sabes ya cuantos resultados trajo?

Comment: Si te fijas en la captura de pantalla si me está trayendo correctamente 5, iniciando a partir del registro 5. Eso funciona de maravilla, Yo necesito saber el total de los registros para hacer funcionar la paginación. Es por eso que agrego la culumna "total", en esa consulta se supone que de acuerdo al criterio de consulta debe traer 17 registros en total, sin embargo, en una casilla está trayendo 48, se supone que si cambio LIMIT 10,5 me va a traeer los próximos 5 de esos 17. Sin embargo me pone en un registro que en total son 48, y eso descompone mi paginación :(  https://prnt.sc/jhif4i

Comment: En teoría, necesito saber cuantos registros trae esa consulta antes de usar el LIMT para poder manipular la paginación: http://prntscr.com/jhifpd

Comment: entiendo, lo que pasa es que ese total, no es el mismo total del otro query, ya que son querys distintos.. tendrias que cambiar la estrategia para contar el total de registros y despues paginar

Comment: Claro, eso lo entiendo pero la verdad no se en donde está la diferencia pues el "and" es el mismo. Mira, se me ocurre separar el query y concatenarle despues el "LIMIT X,Y" para así hacer la consulta directamente son el LIMIT y desde php contar el array, y ya despues consultar con el LIMIT X,Y para hacer que la paginación funcione,  sin embargo al hacer esto se harían 2 consultas al servidor para sacar 1 solo dato, la verdad no estoy seguro de que sea lo más óptimo. ¿me podrías recomendar algo?

Comment: no. no es la misma consulta. una tiene un monton de joins, la otra solo consulta una tabla. ahi te das cuenta del problema?

Comment: Ya encontré el error! :| me diste una pista con los joins, verás, aunque la otra consulta tenga joins, realmente el join nadamás es para mostrar las diferentes columnas, mi error radica en que estoy usando el alias de "vacantes" dentro del count: v.id_estado=30 and v.titulo like , ese alias es para el join no para la sub consulta, he cambiado a: "id_estado=30 and titulo like " y funciona al pelo! PFFF, gracias @gbianchi por tu ayuda de manera indirecta. Un abrazo.

Comment: Esta pregunta dejo de servir? cierrala, borrala, contestala, pero no la dejes asi... y si vas a poner una respuesta, que sea acorde ;)

Comment: Cuenta con ello. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada, gracias @gbianchi por tu tiempo.

El problema está en que estoy haciendo uso del alias de mi consulta principal, no se porque pero al quitar el alias se corrige el asunto.

Entonces quito el alias de la subconsulta quedando así:

```
select (select count(*) from vacantes where id_estado=30 and titulo like 
"%asesor de crédito%" or titulo like '%asesor%' or titulo like '%crédito%' ) 
as total, v.id as idvcante, v.ky, v.titulo, municipios.nombre as municipio, 
estados.nombre as estado, e.id as idempresa, e.empresa, e.img_perfil, 
empresas_contratos_vacantes.tipo, empresas_rangosal_vacantes.rango, 
v.fechapublicacion, empresas_nivexp_vacantes.nivel as experiencia, 
vacantes_cat.categoria, vacantes_subcat.subcategoria from vacantes as v 
inner join municipios on municipios.id=v.id_municipio inner join estados on 
estados.id=v.id_estado inner join empresas as e on e.id=v.id_empresa inner 
join empresas_contratos_vacantes on 
empresas_contratos_vacantes.id=v.id_contrato inner join 
empresas_rangosal_vacantes on 
empresas_rangosal_vacantes.id=v.id_rangosalario inner join 
empresas_nivexp_vacantes on empresas_nivexp_vacantes.id=v.id_experiencia 
inner join vacantes_cat on vacantes_cat.id=v.id_categoria inner join 
vacantes_subcat on vacantes_subcat.id=v.id_subcat where v.id_estado=30 and 
v.titulo like "%asesor de crédito%" or titulo like '%asesor%' or titulo like 
'%crédito%' order by visitas DESC LIMIT 5,5,
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]